# Connectedness of the set $\{(z,w)\in S^3\subset \Bbb C^2:z^m+w^n=0\}$ where $m,n\in \Bbb N$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, complex-numbers, connectedness

For positive integers $m,n$, let $A_{m,n}$ denote the set $\{(z,w)\in S^3\subset \Bbb C^2:z^m+w^n=0\}$. I am trying to show that this set is connected if and only if $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$. Also, in this case, I want to compute the length of $A_{m,n}$. But I have no idea how to start for both statements. Can I get a little bit of hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Waht do you mean by "length"?

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm not sure but I think it means length as a curve, because $A_{m,n}$ is a smooth $1$-manifold

Comment: Seems plausible. But I think you should be absolutely sure what you want to know when you ask a question.